# Flexible progressbar with chapter segments using nested list elements not working in Webkit browsers

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, responsive-design

For an online education website I created a flexible progressbar which is divided into chapters and chapter segments. It has to be flexible in modern browsers, because the project is going to be responsive.

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zyCkW/7/

What I wanted to achieve is that the chapter list elements kind of collapse with 0 pixel width while the child `<li>` elements (chapter segments) float left using a certain percentage of the whole #progressbar. If I let the chapter `<li>` elements float as well or give them 25% width, the segments won't use the #progressbar's width and become much smaller.

**The problem:**

What I wrote works quite well in IE7-9, Firefox and Opera but unfortunately not in Webkit browsers (Chrome/Safari): The chapter descriptions are all positioned left and not, as expected, at the beginning of the first chapter segment. I suppose Webkit is the only browser which handles it right... even if I appreciate the other browser's results.

Is there a solution I can fix this in Webkit, best without Javascript?

Answer (score 0):

I poorly solved it by positioning the chapter descriptions left using the `:nth-child` pseudo-selector.

```
#progressbar ol>li:nth-child(2) span { left: 23.076%; }
#progressbar ol>li:nth-child(3) span { left: 53.844%; }
#progressbar ol>li:nth-child(4) span { left: 76.92%; }
```

I'd still appreciate any better solutions, if possible.